# Why CakePHP 2.0 is not using my AppController?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have just upgraded to Cakephp 2.0 alpha, and immediately faced a problem. The app_controller.php in the app/ folder is not loaded in my controllers. Instead controllers use the CakePHP own AppController.php in the lib/Cake/Controller/AppController.php.

I have tried renaming the app_controller to AppController.php aswell but its not working. I have tried deleting the whole file and then copying the lib/Cake/Controller/AppController.php file and then editing it but not working.

I have also tried deleting cache files.

I just simply use:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        die;
    }
}
```

And the application wont die.

My controller is also simply just:

```
class NewsController extends AppController {
    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
    function index() {
    }
}
```

So what I could be doing wrong? Im also using Windows 7 + Netbeans with Subversion to update project (if that has anything to do with it :p).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did much of searching and didn't look from most obvious place: Github cakephp docs: https://github.com/cakephp/docs/blob/master/en/controllers.rst . I thought they were still 1.3 docs but it appears they are updated. Since they are now updated, it says that I should put the old app_controller.php into Controller folder and camel case it to AppController.php.

Comment: Gaaah you saved me! Thanks for finding this. I guess that's what you get when you tinker with beta. I was following the Cookbook with my fingers crossed. Did not help lol.

Answer (score 2):

Create file AppController.php in app/Controller directory

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Javascript');
    public function beforeFilter() {
        die('app/Controller/AppController.php file called');
        parent::beforeFilter();

    }

}
```